# reloading datatable every button click

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have reloading issue my datatable. I want to reload my datatable every search button clicking. I tried everything to fix this problem but I can't do it. *Can any one help me?*

```
<script>
function getData(){
    var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:";
    var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName:";
    var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType:";
    var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
    var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
    var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
    var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;
    $.ajax({
        url:URL,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        jsonp : 'json.wrf',
        type :'get',
        cache :false,
        success: function(data){
            var docs=JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
            var jsonData=JSON.parse(docs);
            var html='';
            $.each(jsonData,function(key,value){
                html+='<tr>';
                html+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.PackName+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocType+'</td>';
                html+='<td>'+value.DocName+'</td>';
                html+='<td class="text-center"><button id="'+value.FilePath+""+'type="button onclick="openDocument(this.id)" class="btn btn-sm" >OPEN</td>';
                html+='</tr>';
            });
            $('#example').append(html);

            var table=$('#example').DataTable({
                "aaSorting" : [],
            });

        },
    });


};
</script>
```

and here is my running

[image: view]

when i am clicking search button once it works correctly but i am clicking more than once it gives me datatable reinitialize error.

```
<label for="strSO">Sales-Order: </label> <input id="ngramBoxstrSO"></input>
        <label for="PackName">PackName: </label> <input id="ngramBoxPackName"></input>
        <label for="DocType">DocType: </label> <input id="ngramBoxDocType"></input>
        <input type="button" value="SEARCH" onclick="getData()">
        <br><br>

        <table id="example" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-sm table-hover">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 4%">Id</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 7%">SalesOrder</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Document Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Package Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%">Document Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">Open</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="tbody">

            </tbody>


            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Id</th>
                    <th class="text-center">SalesOrder</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Document Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Package Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Document Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Open</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this outside `getData()` function

```
if($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#example' )){
    table = $('#example').DataTable();
}
```

Add this inside `ajax` `success` function

```
table.destroy();
$('#example').append(html);
table=$('#example').DataTable({
    "aaSorting" : []
});
```

Comment: its not working. first button click its working but after first clicking it gives nothing. :(

Comment: I tried this. Its add correct results after all results. For example first searching I have 53 results after then second searching it shows me 67 results.

Comment: replace `append` with `html`

Answer (score 0):

If you gave your html sample, then it would be better to solve. But you can try this:

```
if (typeof table !== 'undefined') {    // write this before your datatable statement
        table.fnClearTable();
    }

var table=$('#example').DataTable({
         "aaSorting" : [],
});
```

Nothing is working for you, so please try following solution:

HTML is this much only without table tag:

```
<label for="strSO">Sales-Order: </label> <input id="ngramBoxstrSO"></input>
        <label for="PackName">PackName: </label> <input id="ngramBoxPackName"></input>
        <label for="DocType">DocType: </label> <input id="ngramBoxDocType"></input>
        <input type="button" value="SEARCH" onclick="getData()">
        <br><br>
        <div class="tableDiv">
       </div>
```

Now, in your `getdata` function:

```
    function getData(){
        var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:";
        var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName:";
        var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType:";
        var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
        var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
        var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
        var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;

    $('.tableDiv').html('');
    tableContent = '<table id="example" class="table table-primary table-bordered table-sm table-hover">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 4%">Id</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 7%">SalesOrder</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Document Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Package Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%">Document Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%">Open</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="tbody">

            </tbody>


            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Id</th>
                    <th class="text-center">SalesOrder</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Document Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Package Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Document Type</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Open</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>';
$('.tableDiv').append(tableContent);
        $.ajax({
            url:URL,
            dataType:'jsonp',
            jsonp : 'json.wrf',
            type :'get',
            cache :false,
            success: function(data){
                var docs=JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
                var jsonData=JSON.parse(docs);
                var html='';
                $.each(jsonData,function(key,value){
                    html+='<tr>';
                    html+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
                    html+='<td>'+value.strSO+'</td>';
                    html+='<td>'+value.PackName+'</td>';
                    html+='<td>'+value.DocType+'</td>';
                    html+='<td>'+value.DocName+'</td>';
                    html+='<td class="text-center"><button id="'+value.FilePath+""+'type="button onclick="openDocument(this.id)" class="btn btn-sm" >OPEN</td>';
                    html+='</tr>';
                });
                $('#example tbody').append(html);

                var table=$('#example').DataTable({
                    "aaSorting" : [],
                });

            },
        });


    };
```

Comment: yes i tried but its not working for me. I dont understand why.

Comment: Try `if (typeof table !== 'undefined') {    // write this before your datatable statement
        table.fnClearTable();
    }` before ajax call

Comment: it gives reinitiliaze error. i will explane my problem with more details. for example i clicked search button after fill sales order label and the results came table. after then i want to filter it with DocType label and i fill DocType label. now sales order and doctype labels are filled and i clicked search button so it gives me reinitialize error.

Comment: I understood your problem. I check your code again and let you know.

Comment: I have a doubt on this statement `$('#example').append(html);`. You are appending records coming through ajax in example table, i think it should be `$('#example tbody').append(html)` and write at start of getData() function `$(#example tbody).html('');`

Comment: If something is not clear from code written in comment, I can edit code in asnwer.

Comment: its gives me same error but when i am clicking okey button in error field correct results coming before all results

Comment: I know correct results will come through ajax but results are not fitting in table due to reintialize error of datatable. Are you sure you are appending to `$('#example')`? because $('#example') is contains everything like `<thead>`. If you write $('#example') instead of `$('#example tbody')`, thead will be removed

Comment: I write it like this `$('#example tbody')`

Comment: Ok, if nothing working. I will give you another solution to you in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your **getData()** function with this one.

```
function getData(){
var URL_PREFIX="http://localhost:8983/solr/archiveCore/select?q=strSO:";
var URL_MIDDLE="AND PackName:";
var URL_SUFFIX="AND DocType:";
var strSO="\"" + $("#ngramBoxstrSO").val() + "\"";
var PackName="\"" + $("#ngramBoxPackName").val() + "\"";
var DocType="\"" + $("#ngramBoxDocType").val() +"\"";
var URL=URL_PREFIX + strSO + URL_MIDDLE + PackName + URL_SUFFIX + DocType;
$.ajax({
    url:URL,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    jsonp : 'json.wrf',
    type :'get',
    cache :false,
    success: function(data){
        var docs=JSON.stringify(data.response.docs);
        var jsonData=JSON.parse(docs);

        $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#example').DataTable({
            data: jsonData,
            columns: [
                { data: 'id' },
                { data: 'strSO' },
                { data: 'PackName' },
                { data: 'DocType' },
                { data: 'DocName' },
                { data: 'FilePath',
                  render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                              return '<button type="button" onclick="openDocument(' + data + ')" class="btn btn-sm" >OPEN</button>';
                  } 
                }
            ]
        })
    },
});
```

Comment: @MustafaBerkanDemir kindly change $('#example').append(html); into $('#example tbody').append(html);

Comment: @MustafaBerkanDemir I edited my post. Kindly check it. I think you should append the html string into the tbody element of the table before initializing it as a datatable

Comment: I tried it bro but it gives me reinitialize error and I clicked okey button the correct results coming before all results. for example all results have 53 data rows and when I am filtering the data. It must give me 14 data rows.

Comment: @MustafaBerkanDemir  I edited my post again. Kindly check it and if there are errors, let me know so that I can assist you.

Comment: @MustafaBerkanDemir Looks like you've already solved the problem. I was gonna tell you to also change "append" to "html", but it seems like Atal just said it. Good luck on your system bro

Answer (score 0):

Try [bDestroy](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options)

```
$('#example').DataTable({
   "aaSorting" : [],
   "bDestroy": true
});
```

Comment: After appending new rows, inspect your table and check if the format of table and rows are ok? Is there something missing e.g. confliction in `<tbody>` and `<tr>` position?@MustafaBerkanDemir